# Rails app. Multiple forms in devise view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, devise

Currently the view/devise/registration/edit has one form for changing password. I want it to have multiple forms, like one for changing password, one to change name of the user... etc.

I tried to just add another form, but when I try to submit it, the form for name tells me that I should enter current password. (this is a field from the other form) How can I isolate the forms? 
This is how the form is created:

```
    <div class="center">
      <div class="devise-controller">
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
                               :url => registration_path(resource_name),
                               :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
          # some fields here...
          <%= f.submit "Update" %>
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Devise already creates separate views for each of them. You can simply override those views. To achieve what you wanted, you need to override the devise's controllers too

Comment: You probably don't need multiple forms, you can add fields for the resource to the existing form so that the user can change their name/email/favourite colour all in one place.

Comment: Thanks fellas. Matt, you are right. I can simply add new fields to the existing form. Interesting how I often can't see the easy way and try to overengeneer. : )

Answer (score 2):

hello please see following links for creating multi-form :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

or

http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=comments